# Stored Procedure calls multiple stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

When calling several stored procedures for one stored procedure is this the right or best way to go about it on SQL Server 2008 ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DoStuff]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @result int
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE @result = dbo.UpdateTHIS @ID = 1            
            IF @result != 0
                ROLLBACK
            ELSE 
                EXECUTE @result = dbo.UpdateTHAT @ID = 21               
                IF @result != 0
                    ROLLBACK
                ELSE
                    EXECUTE @result = dbo.UpdateANOTEHR @ID = 15
                    IF @result != 0
                        ROLLBACK
                    ELSE
                        COMMIT
                        SELECT @result 
        END             
END
```

Comment: Looks good to me except I would use explicit BEGIN and END for each IF and ELSE

Comment: r the IFs nested?...if they r then I'd rather use BEGIN and END to write my logic in them...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly recommend using TRY/CATCH blocks and RAISERROR instead of @@ERROR/@result checks. I have a blog entry that shows how to properly use transactions and TRY/CATCH blocks, including nested transactions to revert only the failed procedure call work so that the calee can resume a different path and continue the transaction, if it feels like: [Exception Handling and Nested Transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/).

**<Update>**

You are being inconsistent with regard to procedures return mode. UpdateTHIS and UpdateTHAT return 0/1 as a return value, while the wrapper DoStuff returns as a result set (SELECT). It means you cannot write DoMoreStuff that calls DoStuff because it has to use INSERT ... EXEC to capture the result, and you'll quickly find out that INSERT ... EXEC cannot nest. I recommend using RETURN @result instead, for consistency.

</update>

I also have an unrelated commend, which is just an element of style: I find long IF... ELSE IF... ELSE IF ... ELSE IF ... blocks difficult to read and follow. I always found that expressing the same as a DO ... BREAK ... BREAK ... BREAK ... WHILE (FALSE) is easier do read. T-SQL does not have a DO ... WHILE construct, so a WHILE ... has to be used instead:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
  EXECUTE @result = dbo.UpdateTHIS @ID = 1;         
  IF @result != 0
  BEGIN
     ROLLBACK;
     BREAK;
  END 

  EXECUTE @result = dbo.UpdateTHAT @ID = 21             
  IF @result != 0
  BEGIN
     ROLLBACK;
     BREAK;
  END

  ...

  COMMIT;
  BREAK;
END
```

Again, this is no important as is just a code formatting style, but is a suggestion in case you agree that it results in code that is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

**Nested ifs and not/nested ifs are different**. Rollback will rollback a transaction, but keep going. I'd had some explicit RETURN commands to gurantee and make it obvious when and where you want the code to exit the stored procedure.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, I don't think calling other stored procs from one stored proc is a very good idea. If there is an error, it would take a lot of man hours to figure out where the error happened. In some cases another developer may change a stored proc without telling anyone in the team. The number of things that can go wrong is too high.

It may be best to write all your sql in one big stored proc.

Edited:
It also depends on how big your stored proc is going to be.

Comment: But at what cost? a multi thousand line stored procedure I maintained once was cut down to one or two hundred lines of code after refactoring into multiple stored procedures.  Making stored procs stand alone will greatly increase the amount of duplicate code found in stored procedures.

Comment: True, I have to agree it depends on how big the stored proc is going to be.

Comment: I totally disagree.  It would be a bad programming practice to repeat code that does the same thing in multiple stored procedures.  Stored procedures are specifically used to encapsulate business or data logic so they can be re-used.
Although there are some limitations to hierarchically call stored procedures from another, the maintenance benefits largely overweight the risks.  Like any "shared" component in an application (like a DLL, or a web service, etc), compatibility after a change is an important issue, but its far from being a huge issue...